# How to create an html context menu where the menu entries changed based on runtime values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contextmenu

I'm unable to answer the question as it's been put on hold. But I've added an update below.

Ok, this is probably a really dumb question - but my head hurts too much now!
I am trying to create a context menu that changes based on certain conditions.

So, purely for example if the hour is less than 8 then show a menu with entries:

- call today,
- visit today
- email

If the hour is between 8 & 4 the entries might be:

- call now
- email now

If the hour is between 4 & 12 then another set of menu entries.
I've tried some examples I've found online but I just seem to be getting more confused now!

Ok, I said it was a dumb question. I had looked at various plugins, such as Audero-Context-Menu @ github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu, MB Menu @ pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/mb-_menu/ and others. I've ended up with [Rodney Rehm's jQuery-contextMenu](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/). After looking through it and some other sources, I was able to take one of the demos and modify it to prototype what I was trying to accomplish. Based on the demo @ hmedialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/dynamic-create.html I modified the code as shown below:

```
$(function(){
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    build: function($trigger, e) {
        // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
        // its results are destroyed every time the menu is hidden
        // e is the original contextmenu event, containing e.pageX and e.pageY (amongst other data)
        return {
            callback: function(key, options) {
                process(key, options)
            },
            items: loadme()
        };
    }
});
});
var count=0;
function process(key, options) {
                    var m = "clicked: " + key;
                    window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
}
function loadme() {
    return {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit "+ (++count)},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
                }
};
```

Basically, each time you bring up the context menu, the count increments for the Edit link in the menu.

P.S. I would use the proper links but I can only use two due to my reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that comment for the `build` param:

```
    // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
```

And you return an object containing the `loadme` function, which increments `count` each time it's called (that's what `++count` does).  The result is that every time a menu shows, `loadme` runs and `count` gets incremented.  You'd want to get rid of the `++` if you don't want the increment to happen.

But i'm thinking this is just an example, and isn't related to what you're really trying to do.  What you almost certainly want is to make `loadme` instead decide which range `(new Date()).getHours()` falls into, and based on that, return an object containing the appropriate menu entries.